# Real analysis question not able to solve.

Tags: real-analysis

let ∑ xn [limit 1 to infinity]be a conditionally convergent series of real numbers. show that there exists a rearrangement ∑ x m that converges to 100

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! What have you tried so far? Also, please use mathjax to format your equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is just a specific case of the statement of the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: The general strategy is to take positive terms until you get above 100, then take negative terms until you get below, and so on. There is a bit of checking to do that things work out.

Comment: @user499968 You need to read up on what this site is for. With all due courtesy, “could u pl post ur ans” is laughable in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a conditionally convergent sequence. Let $\{p_n\}$ be the positive terms, and $\{n_n\}$ be just the negative terms. These series are necessarily divergent. For some $N_1$, the sum of the first $N_1$ terms of $p_n$ will be above 100. Then for some $N_2$, the sum $\sum_{N_1} p_n + \sum_{N_2} n_n$ will be below 100, then for some $N_3$, the sum $\sum_{N_1} p_n + \sum_{N_2} n_n + \sum_{N_1 < n < N_3} p_n$ will be above 100. Continue in this fashion. The resulting series converges to 100, and is a rearrangement of the given series.

Comment: I think that it would be good to add that since the series is conditionally convergent, both sums $\sum p_n$ and $\sum n_n$ diverge.

Comment: Good point. Although I described the method, there are proofs still to be done. They should be made clear. They are: 1. show why the "just the positives" subseries is divergent. And 2. show why the new series is convergent.